# Are time interrupts always followed by a scheduler call?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, scheduling, interrupt

When a timer interrupt occurred the ISR is called to service the interrupt.

Is it okay to assume that every timer interrupt ends with a call to the scheduler on which process should continue running next?

Can that be generalized and say that every interrupt must end in a scheduler call?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case. For x86 with no preempt, apparently `schedule()` is called when returning to userspace (and wherever a system call blocks, also on the idle task). With preempt enabled, it's apparently also called when returning from any interrupt, and also in a few other places, e.g. on `mutex_unlock()` slow path, on certain conditions while receiving network packets, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timer ISR doesn't call `schedule()` directly. It ends up calling `update_process_times()` so the scheduler process accounting information is up to date.

The scheduler is eventually called when returning to userspace. If the kernel is preemptive, it is also called when returning from the timer interrupt to kernelspace.

As an example, imagine a process A which issues a syscall which is interrupted by a device-generated interrupt, that is then interrupted by a timer interrupt:

```
   process A userspace → process A kernelspace → device ISR → timer ISR
                    syscall               device IRQ    timer IRQ
```

When the timer ISR ends, it returns to another ISR, that then returns to kernelspace, which then returns to userspace. A preemptive kernel checks if it needs to reschedule processes at every return. A non-preemptive kernel only does that check when returning to userspace.

In ARM land, the codepath goes broadly like:

- An IRQ received while in userspace ends up calling `__irq_usr`, while an IRQ received while in SVC mode ends up calling `__irq_svc`. IRQs should not be received while in other processor modes.
- In `__irq_svc`, after handling the IRQ, *if the kernel is preemptive*, preemption is not disabled, and a reschedule is needed, the kernel jumps to `svc_preempt`, which calls `preempt_schedule_irq`, which calls `schedule`. Otherwise, no reschedule is done.
- Eventually, the CPU will return to userspace, either from an IRQ handler (`__irq_usr` → `ret_to_user_from_irq`), or from a syscall (`vector_swi` → `ret_fast_syscall`). There, the kernel checks whether there is work to be done, and if a reschedule is needed, `schedule` is called.

Comment: Thank you so much, the best answer I've found so far about the calling flow, very helpful.

Comment: May I ask you that if this flow is possible:

    `process A userspace → timer ISR`

and would this lead to the call `schedule()`?

Comment: @ptr_user7813604: yes, the timer ISR updates timing information, and if it's time for a reschedule, it happens when returning to userspace.